# Drupal: Running Feeds Importer Programatically - Where to Put Code

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-feeds

When running a feeds importer using Cron, the importer times out resulting in an incomplete import. I'm trying to use a script to execute the importer and I've come across this code a few times:

```
<?php
function MODULE_NAME_cron() {
  $name = 'FEED_NAME';
  $source = feeds_source($name);
  $source->import();
}
?>
```

However, when executing this I get an error saying there's no feeds_source() function, which leads me to believe that I just don't know where to put this code (a separate php file just isn't working for me). Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `$source->startImport();` method instaed of `$source->import();`

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer to a similar question over here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90062/programmatically-execute-feed-import/153434#153434 , which might help. in short, in the a form submit hook if your using the batch api, or dont use the batch api if you're doing it non browser (install hook , install profile)

so in your case

```
function load_data(){

// Files to import in specific order.
$files = array(
'challenge_importer' => 'data/challenges.csv',
);

$file_location_base = drupal_get_path('module', 'challenge');
foreach ($files as $feed => $file) {

$feedSource = feeds_source($feed);
// Set the file name to import
$filename = $file_location_base.'/' . $file;
if (!file_destination($filename, FILE_EXISTS_ERROR)) {
$config = $feedSource->getConfig();
$config['FeedsFileFetcher']['source'] = $filename;
$feedSource->setConfig($config);
$feedSource->save();
    while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $feedSource->import());
    }
  }
}
```

could be called from the cron , or use the scheduled execution from the feeds importer